# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySimpleGUI'

Tags: python, module

**Hello everyone, I'm a newbie.**

```
I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySimpleGUI'when I'm trying to import PySimpleGUI Module
```

CMD states that my Python is 3.10.10 and pip is 23.0.1

This is my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI

PySimpleGUI.Window(title="Random Title", layout=[[]], margins=(200, 100)).read()
```

Before that, "PySimpleGUI" wasn't even recognized by Pylance so I followed [This guide](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/5189) to fix the problem and it worked.

So My best guess is, that it's in the wrong location ?

Current location for PySimpleGUI is:

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages

I ran *pip list* to check if the module was installed and it 100% is.

```
Package                   Version
------------------------- ---------
altgraph                  0.17.3
asttokens                 2.1.0
backcall                  0.2.0
cachetools                4.2.4
certifi                   2022.9.24
cffi                      1.15.1
charset-normalizer        2.1.1
colorama                  0.4.6
cryptography              38.0.3
debugpy                   1.6.3
decorator                 5.1.1
entrypoints               0.4
executing                 1.2.0
future                    0.18.2
google-auth               1.12.0
google-auth-oauthlib      0.5.3
gspread                   5.7.0
httplib2                  0.21.0
idna                      3.4
ipykernel                 6.17.1
ipython                   8.6.0
jedi                      0.18.1
jupyter_client            7.4.5
jupyter_core              5.0.0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6
nest-asyncio              1.5.6
oauth2client              4.1.3
oauthlib                  3.2.2
packaging                 21.3
parso                     0.8.3
pefile                    2022.5.30
pickleshare               0.7.5
pip                       23.0.1
platformdirs              2.5.4
prompt-toolkit            3.0.32
psutil                    5.9.4
pure-eval                 0.2.2
pyasn1                    0.4.8
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8
pycparser                 2.21
Pygments                  2.13.0
pyinstaller               5.6.2
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2022.13
pyOpenSSL                 22.1.0
pyparsing                 3.0.9
PySimpleGUI               4.60.4
python-dateutil           2.8.2
pywin32                   305
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0
pyzmq                     24.0.1
requests                  2.28.1
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1
rsa                       4.0
six                       1.16.0
stack-data                0.6.1
tornado                   6.2
traitlets                 5.5.0
urllib3                   1.26.12
wcwidth                   0.2.5
```

Edit: when I ran

```
import sys; print(sys.path)
```

```
  & 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe' 'c:\Users\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '57726' '--' 'c:\Users\User\Desktop\znowu nic nie bedzie\GUI.py' 
['c:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\znowu nic nie bedzie', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python311.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: Maybe this is related to the interpreter you are using to run this code. For instance, if you use a Python 3.x interpreter, you should run `pip3 list` to see all the modules that are actually recognized by your current interpreter.

Comment: You can always use `python -m pip install` to ensure you're using the pip version corresponding to your main Python installation.

Comment: @BarbaraGendron
I've just run "pip3 list" and PySimpleGUI is not on the list... what do I do now ?
Edit:
pip3 install PySimpleGUI states that
Requirement already satisfied: PySimpleGUI in c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (4.60.4)

Comment: Show us the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: It is installed for python3.10, while on your path you have 3.11. The 3.10 is not on your PATH at all. It looks like you have at least 2 python instalations

Comment: Well I do have both:
PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0
&
PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0
In C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages

Does that mean that I need to change PATH to Python 3.11 since VSCode is using 3.11 
OR 
change python to 3.10 in VSCode ?